# Variables and dynamic values for another type

Tags: android, variables

How can i realize following code:

```
    String dynamiccolor = "R.color." + selectedcolor;


    View MainActivity = findViewById(R.id.mainactivity);
    View root = MainActivity.getRootView();
    root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor( dynamiccolor )); 
//here dynamiccolor variable is string, but for errorfree code must be INT
```

How can i use dynamiccolor variable like, for ex R.color.green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method to your code:

```
protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}
```

Then use it so:

```
// Assuming that you have your color resource in colors.xml
final int dynamiccolor = getResourceID(selectedcolor, "color", getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with android, then you would be knowing that R is a static class.
So R.color.green essentially contains an int that maps to your colors.xml file. 
You can try doing something like this:

```
int dynamiccolor = -1;
switch(selectedcolor) {
   case "green": 
      dynamiccolor = R.color.green;
      break;
...
}

View MainActivity = findViewById(R.id.mainactivity);
View root = MainActivity.getRootView();    
root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor( dynamiccolor ));
```